# What is the review counter showing?

Tags: discussion, review

Here comes an odd little low-practical question out of curiosity:

**What does the review counter show**? The little counter in the upper bar is always showing a high number (fluctuating a bit) even when review queues are empty. I might have missed an explanation somewhere when being sworn in with the review privilege.

[image]

It could of course just be because there are more queues than I am [allowed to review at my place in the hierarky](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) (odd that I would see a tempting counter in that case), but there [don't seem to be any queues hidden from me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shows the total number of flags whose review is pending, cf. [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/263383). It also includes those you have already acted on (recall that many reviews need more than one user to complete them) and moderator flags which you cannot see. Additionally, the number is cached and may reflect an older status of the queue.

It annoys me to no end to have a number there but nothing to act on, but you learn to live with it.

Comment: Sounds like it annoyed you to an end.

Comment: Aha. Thank you for answering. A natural follow-up question is then... what is the point? That review count is, for the user himself, completely unusable. Unless he is a diamond moderator.

Comment: @Steeven Good question, I never figured that out.

Comment: [If the review queue gets very long, we may try to draw attention to it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=35121010#35121010).

Comment: @Steeven Who knows. It's [been around for a very long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231051/please-dim-the-color-of-the-review-task-counter-when-there-are-no-actionable-tas), though - and there's really no indication that anything will change there. (See also several linked MSE questions from that link.)